# ¿Cual es el error en este algoritmo? (C++)

Tags: c++, algoritmos, condiciones

Este algoritmo debe ordenar 4 numeros y que los imprima en forma ascendente, hice esto, los compare entre si, pero con los n3 y n4 no me anda bien, porque puede ser? le estuve buscando el error pero no lo encuentro, si alguno me puede dar una mano se lo agradeceria!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () {
    int n1,n2,n3,n4;
    printf("Ingrese el N°1: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("Ingrese el N°2: ");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    printf("Ingrese el N°3: ");
    scanf("%d",&n3);
    printf("Ingrese el N°4: ");
    scanf("%d",&n4);

    if((n1<n2 && n2<n3 && n3<n4)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n1,n2,n3,n4);
    }

    else if ((n1<n2 && n2<n4 && n4<n3)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n1,n2,n4,n3);
    }

    else if((n1<n2 && n3<n2 && n2<n4)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n1,n3,n2,n4);
    }

    else if((n1<n4 && n4<n2 && n2<n3)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n1,n4,n2,n3);
    }

    else if((n1<n4 && n4<n3 && n3<n2)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n1,n4,n3,n2);
    }

    else if((n1<n3 && n3<n4 && n4<n2)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n1,n3,n4,n2);
    }

    else if((n2<n1 && n1<n3 && n3<n4)){

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n2,n1,n3,n4);
    }

    else if((n2<n1 && n1<n4 && n4<n3)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n2,n1,n4,n3);
    }

    else if((n2<n1 && n4<n1 && n1<n3)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n2,n4,n1,n3);
    }

    else if((n2<n1 && n4<n3 && n3<n1)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n2,n4,n3,n1);
    }

    else if((n2<n1 && n3<n1 && n1<n4)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n2,n3,n1,n4);
    }

    else if((n2<n1 && n3<n4 && n4<n1)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n2,n3,n4,n1);
    }

    else if((n3<n1 && n1<n4 && n4<n2)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n1,n2,n4);
    }

    else if((n3<n1 && n1<n4 && n4<n2)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n1,n4,n2);
    }

    else if((n3<n2 && n2<n1 && n1<n4)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n2,n1,n4);
    }

    else if((n3<n2 && n2<n4 && n4<n1)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n2,n4,n1);
    }

    else if((n3<n4 && n4<n1 && n1<n2)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n4,n1,n2);
    }

    else if((n4<n3 && n3<n2 && n2<n1)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n4,n2,n1);
    }

    else if((n4<n1 && n1<n2 && n2<n3)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n1,n2,n3);
    }

    else if((n4<n1 && n1<n3 && n3<n2)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n1,n3,n2);
    }

    else if((n4<n3 && n3<n1 && n1<n2)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n3,n1,n2);
    }

    else if((n4<n3 && n3<n2 && n2<n1)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n3,n2,n1);
    }

    else if((n4<n2 && n2<n1 && n1<n3)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n2,n1,n3);
    }

    else if((n4<n2 && n2<n3 && n3<n1)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n2,n3,n1);
    }
}
```

Comment: No seria mejor que usaras un algoritmo como por ejemplo ordenamiento por burbuja?

Comment: Si pero lo tengo que hacer sin el metodo burbuja, son ejercicios condicionales simples

Comment: Podrias indicarnos que numeros estas ingresando?

Comment: Para asi reproducir el error, por favor

Comment: Ok, tome como valores los siguientes numeros: 1 - 3 - 7 - 10, esos numeros aplico para todas las decisiones

Comment: Si o si tiene que ser con condiciones? No se puede utilizar ningún tipo de estructuras de datos como arreglos?

Comment: nono, si no obvio que utilizaria el metodo burbuja para ordenarlos pero no se puede, yo lo trate de hacer asi y con los n1 y n2 me sale bien pero con los demas algunos me fallan

Comment: con n2 también falla, si metes 4, 3, 2, 1 por ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el séptimo `else if` de abajo hacia arriba te equivocaste:

```
else if((n4<n3 && n3<n2 && n2<n1)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n4,n2,n1);
    }
```

Debería ser:

```
else if((n4<n3 && n3<n2 && n2<n1)) {

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n4,n3,n2,n1);
    }
```

En el 12 también:

```
else if((n3<n1 && n1<n4 && n4<n2)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n1,n2,n4);
    }
```

Debería ser:

```
else if((n3<n1 && n1<n4 && n4<n2)) { 

        printf("\nOrden Ascendente: \n%d \n%d \n%d \n%d",n3,n1,n4,n2);
    }
```

Checa bien el orden de tus condiciones, no sé si haya más errores. Esos fue los que vi más claro.